MongoDB Multi-Region Replica with readPreference=nearest Still Redirecting to Primary Region
I am trying to reduce latency in my application by setting up a multi-region replica using MongoDB Atlas. Initially, my database was hosted in a single region (Mumbai: ap-south-1). To improve latency for users in the US, I created a replica in the US Ohio region (us-east-2).
Here's what I've done so far:
Configured a multi-region setup in MongoDB Atlas with the primary region in ap-south-1 and a replica in us-east-2.
Updated my connection string to include readPreference=nearest to ensure queries are routed to the nearest replica.
Created an API /db-location that fetches and logs the database info in JSON. I asked a US-based client to call this endpoint to verify if their requests are being routed to the us-east-2 replica.
However, the output of /db-location still shows ap-south-1, indicating that requests are still being routed to the Mumbai region.
My Connection String:
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster.example.mongodb.net/mydb?readPreference=nearest&retryWrites=true&w=majority

API Code to Check MongoDB Server Status:
// API to check MongoDB server status
app.get("/db-location", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Check if the MongoDB connection is ready
    if (!mongoose.connection.readyState) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "MongoDB connection is not established" });
    }

    // Access the admin interface and fetch server status
    const admin = mongoose.connection.db.admin();
    const serverStatus = await admin.serverStatus();

    res.status(200).json({
      serverStatus: serverStatus,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
  }
});


Why are requests from the US still being routed to ap-south-1 instead of us-east-2, even with readPreference=nearest?

Is there a better way to verify that requests from the US are being directed to the nearest region (us-east-2)?

Are there any additional configurations required in MongoDB Atlas or my application to achieve the desired behavior?


Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The accessed node is done for every single command, not on connection level. Some operations can be executed only on the primary (I guess db.serverStatus is one of them)

"I asked a US-based client to call this endpoint " Where was the code being hosted?  The origin of the call is not important, "nearest" will be determined by the network round trip time from where the endpoint is being hosted.

Unless you set a different readPreference with Mongo.setReadPref it should work fine.
However, some commands can run only on the PRIMARY. Command db.serverStatus() return numbers for readPreferenceCounters, so I guess this commands reads data from all nodes and is not suitable to check which node was queried.
Maybe have a look at the explain plan, it may show on which node the query is running (I did not test). Or have a look at currentOp command. The most reliable check would be to have a look at the logfile of the MonogDB member. You can download them in Atlas.
